# I have 4 columns in an MS Excel file, I want to search for a specific word for the specific range from the whole column. Please suggestme the formula

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns in an excel file, column A contains the values of kilometers starting from 0 to 300, column b contains the letters, PH, PP etc. I want to search "PP" within every 1.6km interval i.e. 0-1.6, 1.6-3.2... and the function should return for every 0-1.6, 1.6-3.2... if there is a word "PP" in the other column.

Comment: What intervals are the values in column A in? Is it like 0, 1, 2, ..., 300? If so, for the category 1.6-3.2 (for example), do you want the function to return TRUE if there is a "PP" next to either 2 or 3? Or both 2 or 3? Perhaps a screenshot of your spreadsheet and some example TRUE / FALSE values may help us understand better.

Comment: Sir, there are four columns first contains values of distance in m or km i.e. 0.432, 0.526, 0.789, 1.258, 1.678 ....300. The other column contains number of houses at the particular kilometer e.g. against 0.526 there could be a house and against that house in the third column there would be 'PD', if there is a temple in second column then there would be PP in the third column like that. I have to see for every 1.6km interval of column 1, there is any mention of PP in the third column. I have sumif function of excel to calculate number of houses between every 1.6km

Comment: I have a solution which does not require any VBA, just posting it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Spreadsheet]

Column A contains the distances, and B the values (B is actually the "third column" from your spreadsheet).

We copy down the values in column E, so they populate automatically, 1.6 apart. Be sure to go one further than you need, to include the end-point of the last interval.

Then in column D, I used the formula `=E2 & " - " & E3` to populate the names of the intervals (for easier reading).

Column F counts the number of cells in column A which are in the interval or below it. So 3 cells in column A in in 0-1.6, 8 cells in column A are in 0-3.2, etc... I used `=COUNTIF(distances,"<"&E3)` to do this.

Column G counts the "PP"s in B up until the end of the current interval. `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B1:B"&F2),"PP")` does this.

Column H counts the hits in that particular interval. In H2, just put `=G2`. In H3, put `=G3-G2` and drag down.

Finally, column I returns TRUE if column H is nonzero.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your response, I want to share three JPEG files for your better understanding, but dont know how to share. please tell me.

Comment: Perhaps upload to imgur or similar and share a link in these comments?